# HTML: Image not displaying

Tags: html, django

I am using Django.  I have an `.html` file, `main.html`, in the following project folder

```
/home/bugs/django_projects/mysite/home/templates/home/main.html
```

In the same folder I have an image Bugs.jpg.  Eg

```
/home/bugs/django_projects/mysite/home/templates/home/Bugs.jpg
```

I am trying to include the image in the webpage via: `<img src="Bugs.jpg">`, but the image does not display.  I have tried debugging via: https://sebhastian.com/html-image-not-showing/, but I appear to be referencing the correct location of the file.  The full code for `main.html` is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>B. Rabbit</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Applications</h3>

    <ul>
        <li><p><a href="/polls">A Polls Application.</a></p></li>
        <li><p><a href="/hello">Hello World Application.</a></p></li>
    </ul>

    <img src="Bugs.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why the image is not displaying at all?

**Edit**

Additional information in response to the below questions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong with the HTML. Everything looks correct. However, 404 means file not found. Hence, you need to ensure that the file is being hosted/served properly.

Comment: But why is the file not found when it is sitting in the folder and I believe I am pointing it in the right place as it is in the same folder as the html file?  I also tried an absolute path without success either.

Comment: run command `tree` in terminal inside templates folder and paste its result here, it might help other to answer you question.

Comment: Just having a file sitting in the folder doesn't gaurantee it's being served properly. You need to review (1) your web server configuration - it may not be enabled for jpg mime types, (2) I noticed Bugs.jpg begin with a capital "B" that could have something to do with it, if you're on linux and the file is actually lowercase "b", (3) there could be read permissions problems. So, essentially, the problem is no longer inspecting the HTML itself. It's to do with your webserver configuration.

Comment: The django docs have a [page on serving static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/).

Comment: Thanks.  Have it sorted now.  I didn't realise loading static files were a bit different under django.  The documentation helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your project path, I guess you are working with a django project. In django , loading static files is a bit different. You should create a `static` folder in root of your project and place the image there. Then add the folder in settings.py and then you can load image file in your html like this:
In top if you html file

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    ...
```

And load image like this:

```
<img src="{% static "Bugs.jpg"%}">
```

Read docs to learn more:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/